# HoloViews and Grouped Bar Chart

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

The last example in http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Bars.html doesn't work.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-40b1ef4f775a> in <module>()
      4 keys = product(index, groups)
      5 bars = hv.Bars([k+(np.random.rand()*100.,) for k in keys],
----> 6                ['Index', 'Group'], 'Count')
      7 bars.relabel(group='Grouped') + bars.relabel(group='Stacked')

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

How do I get the grouped bar chart in the last figure of that link? Also, I don't want the labels "a" and "b" below each bar. Just the group labels "A" and "B".

Packages:

```
bokeh=0.12.7=py36_0
holoviews=1.8.4=py36h6f73470_0
jupyter=1.0.0=py36_3
jupyter_client=5.1.0=py36h9902a9a_0
```

**UPDATE**

The example in http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/bars_economic.html also doesn't work. Similar errors. I was able to make it work by changing the script to:

```
macro_df = pd.read_csv('http://assets.holoviews.org/macro.csv', '\t')
key_dimensions   = [('year', 'Year'), ('country', 'Country')]
value_dimensions = [('unem', 'Unemployment'), ('capmob', 'Capital Mobility'),
                    ('gdp', 'GDP Growth'), ('trade', 'Trade')]
macro = hv.Table(macro_df)
```

and then:

```
%%opts Bars [stack_index=1 xrotation=90 width=600 show_legend=False tools=['hover']]
%%opts Bars (color=Cycle('Category20'))
macro.to.bars(kdims=['year', 'country'], vdims='trade', groupby=[]).redim.label(year="Year", trade="Trade")
```

Note that some variables are unused.

Comment: HoloViews is a relatively young project, so some API churn at this stage is not surprising. Are you sure the version of HoloViews that you have installed matches the version of the docs you are referencing? As an aside: It is ***always*** advised to include relevant version information in any question to save time and effort.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the versions. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the docs you linked are for the latest version 1.9.1 at the moment. I expect that explains things.

Comment: I'm unable to install that version. `conda install -c ioam holoviews` downloads the version 1.8.4.

Comment: Not sure what's going on for you, when I do that I get `holoviews:  1.8.1-py36_0         --> 1.9.1-py36hc83329d_0   ioam` as expected. Probably worth pinging the HV team to ask them what's going on.

Comment: There might be some other packages installed that are preventing the latest version from being installed; you could try ``conda install -c conda-forge holoviews`` to see if it's any different (though I don't *think* it will be).  In any case, that's definitely the problem; the positional syntax for kdims and vdims was not introduced until 1.9.x or so.  You should be able to find a compatible version of all the examples included with your installation.

Comment: I should mention that I happen to have Anaconda for Python 2, but created an environment for Python 3 called py3. So I've been installing packages using `-n py3`. @JamesA.Bednar, your suggestion worked for me. I also had to upgrade Bokeh (Holoviews required >=0.12.10). The examples work now. :)

Comment: Can someone comment on my question regarding the labels below the x-axis? I'd like to only display the top-level group (A or B). Also, the x-axis label should only refer to that top-level group. Previously, I was getting a comma-separated label for each group.